# How are particles perceived at an expert level?

Tags: particles

こんにちは！

I was wondering how exactly particles are mentally translated on an expert/native level. When one hears the particle do they quickly associate it with the preceding term, or by that time has it become natural to a point to immediately understand what one is saying? I'd also like to know if there are there any tips for translating sentences without getting overwhelmed by things like particles.

よろしくおねがいします！

Comment: While I'm not a native and can't really answer the question, I imagine they're perceived much like prepositions in English. "Meet me ***in*** the kitchen ***at*** ten o'clock ***for*** dinner." When you acquire a language, the brain just kind of does the work for you.

Comment: For a native monolingual speaker of Japanese, what would it even mean to "mentally translate" particles? Translate to _what_?

Comment: @senshin I mean translate to something you understand, to mentally identify what the person is talking about.

Comment: For me as a fluent nonnative speaker, none of this ever goes through my mind. I simply hear a sentence and understand the meaning, and the intermediate steps are so instantaneous that I have no conscious awareness of the process.

Comment: @Colbi Think about a language you're a native speaker of. Can you describe how you translate a sequence of words into meaning? For a native speaker, it just _happens_. (This is part of why natural language processing is an area of major research - if we could just introspect our own understanding of language and describe how we convert words to meaning, NLP sure would be easy!)

Comment: @senshin Ah I see, this topic is more complicated and uncertain than it seems. Then perhaps the only way to become more natural with particles and get better at translating them is to practice.